# How to make sure linux machine boots if RAID 1 boot drive fails

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, embedded, raid1

I am designing a system that includes a linux (Debian) based control computer. It will be deployed to a remote, inaccessible location. I want to set it up in such a way to maximize the chance that it can boot in spite of disk failures or corruption.

So far, I have set up two industrial SATA DOMs in RAID 1 (mirrored) with GRUB loaded on both MBRs. This seems to work pretty well: I can unplug either drive and the system will still run and reboot.

However, I encountered one situation where one drive got corrupted and then on reboot the RAID failed to assemble, but the system tried to boot of the corrupted drive and got stuck.

If I detect that one drive fails in the RAID 1 array while the system is running, would the safest thing to do be to `dd` zero the failed drive to ensure the system doesn't try to use the corrupt drive and move onto the next?

Would it be more reliable to make the two drives identical and not use RAID 1, and then if a drive fails, disable it from booting in BIOS?

Comment: Use 3 devices and raid5.

Comment: @IporSircer: Unfortunately that's not an option here. I'm looking for the best options given only two disks. I'm actually wondering if it is more reliable to have just one disk.

Comment: then write your own mini shellscript which assembles raid array in initrd based on timestamp. mdadm default always use the first detected device as clean when using raid1.